# Projections T/F

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to say whether or not the following statement is true or false. If true, give a proof and if false, give a counterexample.

If ⃗ = (1, 2, ⋯ , 
) ∈ ℜ
 such that proj⃗ ⃗ = ⃗0 for all  ∈ ℜ
, then ⃗ = ⃗0 .

So, If I use proof by contradiction and say that u is a non zero vector and let u be <1,2,3> and vector v = <4,5,6>, then by using the projection formula of u along v .. I can say that the projection does not equal to zero, so therefore the statement is true ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove the result with an example. The correct argument is as follows: if $u$ is not zero then taking $v=u$ and using the formula for the projection we see that the projection is not zero. Hence the result is true.